# Why byte array in vb6 have numbers different from 1 or 0?

Tags: vb6, byte

I'm trying to make a program that use byte arrays but i saw something interesting.

When i put any string inside a vb6 byte array, then i can see numbers different from 1 or 0 in the array positions.

Example:

```
Dim B() As Byte

B = "coolbyte"

MsgBox (B(0))
```

The value showing in the MessageBox is equal to 99.

Comment: http://www.asciitable.com/

Comment: Bytes can have values from 0 to 255, so 99 is totally ok

Comment: I believe you're confusing bits, and bytes.

Comment: 99 is the ASCII for 'c' and so is correct